# Parsing HTML after POST method

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, parsing, nsstring

I'm trying to parse a website that is after a Login into an iOS application. Parsing the HTML tags works fine with hpple but I have problems by retrieving the HTTP code after the POST method.

Firstly I do this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user": @"username",@"password": @"password"};
[manager POST:@"http://web" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    ResponseData = responseObject;
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", ResponseData);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

And then I retrieve the responseObject where I suppose is my HTML code.

After that I parse that HTML code with this code:

```
NSString* stringwithdata = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ResponseData.bytes];
NSData *tutorialsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:stringwithdata];

TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:tutorialsHtmlData];

NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"/html/head/title";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
Tutorial *tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];
TFHppleElement *element = [tutorialsNodes objectAtIndex:0];
tutorial.title = [[element firstChild] content];
[newTutorials addObject:tutorial];
```

But the compiler returns this stuff:

```
2013-10-24 11:19:47.832 HtmlParsing[1565:70b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
```

I don't know how to access to the HTML data that returns the POST.

P.D. The parser code is not the problem, I've tried it loading a web directly without POST.

Comment: can you try just using `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:ResponseData];`

Comment: I've tried it, the compiler error dispears but the parser doesn't work. It seems as if the stringwithdata does not have HTML format :(